# Error while coding for java xml parser

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

I have coding below:

```
            try{                                
            address = "http://isbndb.com//api/books.xml? 
            access_key=CKEHIG4D&index1=isbn&value1=" +barcode;
            URL url = new URL(address);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(conn.getInputStream());

            NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("BookData");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
                NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("LongTitle");
                Element line = (Element) title.item(0);
                titleList.add(line.getTextContent());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and theXML format is

http://isbndb.com//api/books.xml?access_key=CKEHIG4D&index1=isbn&value1=1593270615

the error is the line --> NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("LongTitle");

Actually what's wrong with that?

Comment: the method getElementsByTagName(String)is undefined for the type Element

Comment: NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("TitleLong");

Comment: Change "LongTitle" --> "TitleLong"

Comment: changed...but still the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change "LongTitle" --> "TitleLong"

in

```
NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("LongTitle");
```

Comment: NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("BookData");

this already declare it...am i correct?

Comment: No, the node list in the problematic line

Comment: still cant run~ the same erro

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are importing the right Element class ([org.w3c.dom.Element](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Element.html)).